# Printing out each time 2 more elements of an array

Tags: c

How can I print out each line two more elements of an array...?
I can't get it done.
I have this short code, but this part is missing...

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *toChar(int numbers[]);

int main(){
//  FILE *fp;
    int num;
    printf("Number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    int val[num], value=num;
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
        val[i]=value;
        value+=value;
        printf("%d ", val[i]);
            ...
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTq69.png)... for `input = 4`.

```
4   8
12  16  20  24
28  32  36  40  44  48
52  56  60  64  68  72  76  80
```

And for input `3`, expected output is:

```
3   6
9   12  15  18
21  24  27  30  33  36
```

Note that the printed value should increase by the same amount as there should be rows (`num`).

Comment: Yes @TedLyngmo. Sorry for not stating that in the question...

Comment: Please show the output as text not as an image.

Comment: I added it @kaylum

Comment: What if the user inputs `3`?

Comment: For 3... same schema, multiples of first element (3) in 3 rows, each row has 2 more elements than the previous... and the first row has 2 elements. So 2-4-6 elements.

Comment: Thank you for the edit @जलजनक. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would make a list of all you need:

- You need `num` rows
- You need the number of columns to increase by 2 every row
- You need the printed value to increase by `num` for each output

With that list, make two loops.

- One that iterates over the rows
- One that iterates over the columns:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Number of rows: ");

    int num;
    if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1) return 1;

    // row starts at 0 and ends at num-1
    // columns start with 2 and increases by 2 for every row
    for (int row = 0, columns = 2, value = num; row < num; ++row, columns += 2) {
        // and value increases by `num` every time it's been printed:
        for (int c = 0; c < columns; ++c, value += num) {
            printf("%d ", value);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nPr1x73W1)

Comment: Thank you very much... I'll edit it a little bit, because the "number of rows" expression actually defines the value of the first element too...

Comment: @askingforhelp You're welcome. If you check the answer, you'll notice that it's been updated after you made your comment about how the value is supposed to be updated too :-) The demo shows example inputs from 1 to 9.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Exactly what I wanted... I'll study the code...

Answer (score 0):

Decided to take a stab at this using java. I feel like recursion here was a bit easier than trying to wrap my head around two for loops.

```java
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    printTwoMore(0, 1, 1, 4);
  }

  public static void printTwoMore(int prevTimesToPrint, int multiple, int currentRow, int maxRow) {

    if (currentRow > maxRow) {
      return;
    }

    int timesToPrint = 2 + prevTimesToPrint;

    for (int i = 0; i < timesToPrint; i++) {
      System.out.print(4 * multiple + " ");
      multiple++;
    }

    System.out.println("");

    currentRow++;

    printTwoMore(timesToPrint, multiple, currentRow, maxRow);
  }

}
```